# Find + Grep Recursive Search

Tags: grep, find, wget, mirror

I am mirroring a website using wget.
On the server, there is a dump of the `find /` command, which includes filenames in the form :

`/dir1/
/dir1/page1.txt
/dir1/page2.txt
...`

The mirrorring is very large (100GB+) and I would like to compare the local output of `find` to the text file containing the server-side dump, so as to have an idea of how many files are left.

I was thinking of using a `grep -v ...` or `awk` but I'm not quite sure how one would go about doing that.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `comm` (using `bash` process substitution):

```
comm -13 <(find / | sort) <(sort server_dump)
```

This will show the files which are unique to the server. For files that are unique to the local system:

```
comm -23 <(find / | sort) <(sort server_dump)
```

You may also wan to add the `-xdev` option to find to stop it from comparing files on other filesystems, such as `/proc` and `/sys`.

Comment: This is pretty good in theory, but it doesn't work in practice – is there a way to make it more flexible ? E.g. that the files don't need to be exactly, line by line, in the same order, and for example the out put of `find` is in an absolute format /pathToMirrorDirectory/dir1... ; so there is a mismatch.

Comment: This ended up being the way to go. I just dupplicated the dump and appended /PathToMirrorDirectory/ before each line. Kind of ugly – but it worked. Thank you !

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne, unfortunately sorting is necessary for `comm`. You can always use `-printf '%P\n'` with `find` to strip the location argument from you path or worst case add a `sed` process to alter the paths. It depends on the exact commands you are actually using though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use `wget's` recursive downloading options because you *already* have a list of the files that need downloading:

```
wget --input-file=./path/to/your/list --base=URL
```

In this way you would just follow the list in the first place, and so every file downloaded would be just the next in the list. So you could always find your progress by merely checking against the last file downloaded and its position in the list.

But if that doesn't work:

```
{ find . ; sed 's/.*/.&/' list.file ; } | 
    sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already launched the mirror. Besides – the recursive download is useful, in case the dump wasn't updated or something ! :)

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne I put another solution up, and I'd be curious just to know if it worked.

Comment: I upvoted because this seems like a good way to tackle this, but the code doesn't run atm; after searching a bit why it seems to say the Mac OS X (which I'm trying to run this on) doesn't have the same sed as the GNU standard. 
But thanks :)

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne I think its because of `/dev/stdin` - either that or you're right and the problem is `-f` - which breaks the streamed model - or `s:`. You can - and probably should - get gnu tools for the mac - in my opinion.

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne if the process substitution in Graeme's answer works you could try: `sed -f <(find /./path/from/root | sed 's:/./path/from/root/to/base/dir(.*):\\|\1|d:') ./path/to/list` but you already have a working solution, so it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne actually, this update is worth your while to try. It will work faster than `comm`. It's simpler to understand as well. The only thing you might have to do is use `sed` instead of `cat` oh, I'll just show it.

Comment: Will try it tonight juste out of raw curiosity! Will comment back asap. Thanks !

Comment: The second method (update) works very well. I like it because I can actually understand it intuitively... haha thanks :)

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne - you can switch accepted answers. Sorry Graeme - but i dont think i can earn any more regular points today...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just dump the output of `find` to a file, on both hosts, and then do a `diff` on the two files? To get the number of files, you could count using `wc`.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the question if there is SSH access available to the server. If there is, I would simply use `rsync` for the job.

Comment: Would be useful — but the mirrored server isn't under my control. This is clandestine to say the least, haha